# Grouping a Pandas DataFrame by Months for Distributor Names

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnHba.png

Essentially, there is a distributor name column, a sales column, and a MM/DD/YYYY Date column.

For each distributor, by month, I want the sum of sales.
What I tried:
df = df.groupby(df['Distributor Name'],df.Date.dt.month)['Sales'].sum()

This throws an error. "Unhashable type: Series". This works when I remove Distributor Name, but I don't just want the overall monthly sales. I want the monthly sales BY distributor.

Thanks in advance!!
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to group by multiple columns is to put them in a list as a first argument:

```py
result = df.groupby(['Distributor Name', df.date.dt.month])['Sales'].sum()
```

This creates a multiindex pandas series, with `Distributor Name` and `Date` as indices. If you wish to create a dataframe with three columns (`Distributor Name`, `Date`, `Sales`) you can reset index of this pandas series.

```py
result = result.reset_index()
```